# Fundamental theorem of algebra, incomplete proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra:

If $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z^1 + ... + a_nz^n$, there exists a complex $w$ such that $p(w) = 0$.

In this exercise exercise I'm supposed to do it in a certain way:
Suppose this $w$ doesn't exist. We will find a contradiction. Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{p(z)}$.

First step of the proof was to show that:

$|z| \gt R $ --> $|z^nf(z)| \lt \frac{2}{|a_n|}$

After doing some other steps I've proved:

$F(x) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^xe^{iy})dy$

Is a constant function. Now what's left for me to prove is:

$(1)$ For every $r \geq 0$,

$2\pi f(0) = \int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{iy})dy $

$(2)$ Using this information I'm now supposed to prove $f(w) = 0$, and finish the proof.

Now I wouldn't know how to do either of these steps, and especially find the last step confusing, because I think $f(0) = \frac{1}{a_0}$ everytime. I'd really like to get some insight in how to prove step (1), and also how to use that to prove step (2).  I hope someone can help me out :)

**Edit:**
The way I proved that F is a constant function (**correct me if I'm wrong**):

I know the following statements are equivalent:

- $f$ is complex differentiable and $f'$ is continuous in point a
- There exists a function $h$ continuous in a such that $f(z) - f(a) = h(z)(z-a)$

it's easy to check that the second statement is indeed true, so the first one is as well. Now: write $z = x +iy$ and prove:
$\frac{d}{dx}f(e^z) = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dy}f(e^z)$

Given the symmetry of the function:
$\frac{d}{dx}f(e^z) = \frac{d}{d(iy)}f(e^z) = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dy}f(e^z)$

So now I can also write:
$F(x) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^xe^{iy})dy = i\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^xe^{iy})dx$

That shows that F(x) is constant, as there is no variable $x$ in the function after integrating it with respect to $x$ over the given boundary.

Comment: I guess $F(x)$ is "more" than a constant function, I feel $F=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the post to show how I found $F$ is a constant. I do not think  that you can know that it equals 0 in this case, but I did think that too. Can't think of a way to show that unfortunately.

Comment: Step (1) is by The Cauchy-Riemann integral formula. If $p$ is never $0$ then $f$ is analytic everywhere so $f(0)=$ $(2\pi i)^{-1}\int_{|z|= r}z^{-1}f(z)dz$ for all $r>0.$ In the integral let $z=re^{iy}$ with  $r$ constant and $y\in [0,2\pi].$ Then $dz=rie^{iy}dy.$

Comment: I haven't heard of that one before, but that is very helpful, thanks! I tried doing the second part as well but didn't manage to complete it. Still curious to the answer, so if someone knows I'd be interested in seeing it:)